# Explanation of this abstract algebra permutations problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

For $m \geq 2$, let $\alpha = (a_0 a_1 \dots a_{m-1}) \in Perm(S_n)$ and 
$\beta = (a_ 0 a_{m-1})\cdots (a_0 a_1) = \prod_{i=0}^{m-2} (a_0 a_{(m-1) - i}) \in Perm(S_n)$.

Show that $\alpha = \beta$. Hint: clearly, $\alpha (x) = \beta(x) = x$ for all $x \not \in \{ a_0,a_1,\dots, a_{m-1} \}$. Thus, we must show that $\alpha (x) = \beta (x)$ for every $x \in \{ a_0, a_1, \dots, a_{m-1} \}$. Split this into three cases: $x =a_0$; $x = a_{m-1}$; and $x \in \{ a_1, \dots, a_{m-2} \}$.

Can someone help me out with this problem? Not sure what approach to take.

Comment: Did you try taking the approach suggested in the hint? "Split this into three cases: $x=a_0;x=a_{m-1};$ and $x\in\{a_1,\dots,a_{m-1}\}$"? What happened when you tried that approach? Did you succeed in any of the three cases?

Comment: Im not understanding why the hint says x is not in the set, but then we must show that every x is in the set.

Comment: That's not what the hint says. Read it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a_1$ only appears in the rightmost transposition, we see that
$$
\beta\colon a_0\mapsto a_1
$$
Similarly $\beta\colon a_{m-1}\mapsto a_0$.

What about $a_i$, with $0<i<m-1$? We have
$$
(a_0a_i)\colon a_i\mapsto a_0
$$
and
$$
(a_0a_{i+1})\colon a_0\mapsto a_{i+1}
$$
so $\beta\colon a_i\mapsto a_{i+1}$, because no other transposition acts on $a_{i+1}$.